# Does ROS2 support keyed topic?

Tags: ros, ros2, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

As stated in the title, does ROS2 have topic with keys? I have been studying ROS2 for few weeks and I have looked around but cannot find anywhere stating about keyed topic in ROS2.

Maybe I have missed something or ROS2 uses this properties in a different way. Thanks in advance for any answer!

Cheers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345545/does-ros2-support-keyed-topic?/) by [Sapodilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/46788/sapodilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2020-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer: No.

Long answer: You can make them keyed by placing the topics in the keyed namespaces so that you get just the instance required. For instance if you have the poses of robots on the `pose` topic, it may look like `/robot1/pose` `/robot2/pose`.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-03-02**:
This isn't a complete substitution since you can't subscribe to *all* `pose` topics in every namespace with a single subscriber.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-03-02**:
True, but its a reasonable work around (unless you have in mind a better way?), and you can programmatically have a vector of subscribers checking for a `/some/namespace/ending/with/pose`.

**Comment by [Sapodilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/46788/sapodilla/) on 2020-03-03**:
Thanks Steven! Since your answer is sufficient for me, I mark it as correct one.